# Saving user settings [winforms] 2.0 not working

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have a code segment to save the state of checkboxes which will run when user is closing the form. Everything runs fine but there is no save file generated (user.config file doesn't get generated). It's my first time using the save settings so I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrongly or missing something.

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Control ctr in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr is CheckBox)
            {
                var cb = (CheckBox)ctr;

                SettingsProperty property = new SettingsProperty("ChkState" + i);
                property.PropertyType = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.CheckState);
                SettingsPropertyValue propertyValue = new SettingsPropertyValue(property);
                propertyValue.PropertyValue = cb.CheckState;
                Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues.Add(propertyValue);
                i++;
            }
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Comment: have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ?

Comment: This is by design, the properties that are stored in a .config file are declared in the app.exe.config file.  Yours are not in there of course.  Add a setting to your project that can store these values.  Of a collection type, like ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you don't create the settings at run time and save them.  The settings have to already exist and you simply save their values.  Add a setting of an appropriate type in the Settings page of the project properties and then get the value of that setting at startup and save it at shutdown.

Is there a specific reason that you're using `CheckState` rather than `Checked`?  Can your `CheckBox` controls be in the `Indeterminate` state?  If not then you should not be using `CheckState` at all.  You use `Checked` to determine whether box is checked or not.

If you can use `Checked` then you can use a single `int` to store the state of up to 32 `CheckBox` controls.  Each of the 32-bits can be 1 to indicate `true`, i.e. checked, or 0 to indicate `false`, i.e. unchecked.

Of course, you can also just use individual settings of type `bool` and bind them to your `Checked` properties.  That way, there's no need to move the data back and forth between the settings and the controls.  You just call `Save` on shutdown and everything else happens automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea